# What is the purpose of the YOUR COMMUNITIES section in the Stack Exchange site list?

Tags: discussion

I am currently a member of 8 Stack Exchange communities:

1. English Language & Usage
2. Meta Stack Exchange
3. Mathematics
4. Stack Overflow
5. Physics
6. Network Engineering
7. Android Enthusiasts
8. Gardening & Landscaping

When I click on the Stack Exchange icon [image] at the far right of the top navigation bar, a scrolling window opens. The window contains 3 sections: CURRENT COMMUNITY, YOUR COMMUNITIES, and MORE STACK EXCHANGE COMMUNITIES. The YOUR COMMUNITIES list only shows 5 of the 8 communities I’ve joined.

[image]

I’ve determined that the list is modifiable and that communities can be added and removed from the list. In fact, it is possible to add a community I have not joined. I found this confusing. I was expecting the list to be auto populated with the communities I’ve joined.

What is the purpose of the YOUR COMMUNITIES section?

Comment: Quick navigation for switching between communities?

Comment: So it doesn't have to do with communities you've joined?

Comment: You might be interested in communities you did not join. Maybe you frequently read on a particular community for which you don't have an account.

Comment: @SLax Welcome to Meta SE. FYI, using a [site search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22your+communities%22), there are quite a few related posts here (although several are now at least somewhat out of date), e.g., [How are the sites listed under "Your Community" picked?](/q/217841), [Custom ordering for "Stack Exchange All Sites" dropdown](/q/215928), ["Your Communities" should show more than 5 sites](/q/222409), etc.

Comment: Thank you for the insight and related questions. I am trying to become a better user of the Stack Exchange platform. I find it to be an exceptional resource for acquiring knowledge. Being a novice user, I am still trying to make sense of all the terms that the Stack Exchange platform uses. I recently looked at some of my profiles and they all have a section titled "Communities". The section contains all the communities I've joined. I guess I miss-associated the "YOUR COMMUNITIES" list with that list. Given what I now know, the "YOUR COMMUNITIES" list is a communities of interest list.

Comment: The real question is why is the UI YELLING AT ME about my communities?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can show more than five - any that you wish by clicking on the "Edit" button on the left side of the row. Here's mine:

[image: My site switcher menu showing MSE, Movies & TV, English Language Learners, Seasoned Advice, Interpersonal Skills, Arts & Crafts, Meta Stack Overflow, and MathOverflow Meta.]

I use them for a variety of reasons... such as:

- Quick access to sites I'm frequently posting on.
- Reference my reputation on specific sites.
- A one-click button to meta sites from anywhere (not possible anywhere else).
- "YOUR COMMUNITIES" is a quick way to get to my network account.

Note, once you customize them, they won't update unless you "Reset" them to default. While I don't customize it often, I find it to be really useful.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is extremely helpful. I now understand the purpose of the "YOUR COMMUNITIES" section. My original confusion stemmed from the "Communities" section found in my account profiles. I miss-associated the "YOUR COMMUNITIES" section with that section. From now on, I'll think of the "YOUR COMMUNITIES" list as a modifiable "Communities of Interest" list.